# How can I run php files?

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed apache2  mysql php5 in my Computer. Files which are in var/www/html directory run properly. I want to run my Files from my home directory.

Comment: post your code lol. Or are you wanting to open a page in your home directory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run PHP from the terminal just go to the folder where the file is located and execute:

```
php file.php
```

If you want to open a `.php` file in web browser from a path other than `/var/www/html`, you will have to change the document root defaults in `/etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/`. After that restart apache and give it a go.

Also make sure that the group and others can access files inside the folder. `755` should do it.